# Importing Qualtrics Responses using Python Requests library

Tags: python, python-requests, qualtrics

I am trying to import a csv of responses into Qualtrics using the API shown here: https://api.qualtrics.com/docs/import-responses. But, since I'm a noob at Python and (by extension) at Requests, I'm having trouble figuring out why I keep getting a 413. I've gotten this far:

```
formTest = {
    'surveyId': 'my_id',
    'file': {
        'value': open('dataFiles/myFile.csv', 'rb'),
        'options': {
            'contentType': 'text/csv'
        }
    }
}

headersTest = {
    "X-API-TOKEN": "my_token",
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data"
}

r = requests.request("POST", url, data=formTest, headers=headersTest)
print(r.text)
```

The format for the formTest variable is something I found when looking through other code bases for an angular implementation of this, which may not apply to a python version of the code. I can successfully use cUrl, but Python Requests, in my current situation is the way to go (for various reasons).

In a fit of desperation, I tried directly translating the cUrl request to python requests, but that didn't seem to help much either.

Has anyone done something like this before? I took a look at posts for importing contacts and the like, but there was no luck there either (since the data that needs to be sent is formatted differently). Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best not to mix post data and files but use two separate dictionaries. For the files you should use the `files=` parameter, because it encodes the POST data as a Multipart Form data and creates the required Content-Type headers.

```
import requests

url = 'Qualtrics API' 
file_path = 'path/to/file'
file_name = 'file.name'

data = {'surveyId':'my_id'}
files = {'file' : (file_name, open(file_path, 'rb'), 'text/csv')}
headers = {'X-API-TOKEN': 'my_token'}

r = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

The first value in `files['file']` is the file name (optional), followed by the file object, followed by the file content type (optional).
You will find more info in the docs: [Requests, POST a Multipart-Encoded File](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file).

Comment: I am getting an error, FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dataFiles/Correction of CW.csv' 

Like my survey is called "Correction of CW" how may I call it from qulatrics through python

Comment: @rsc05 The file must be in the same path as the path where your script is running from, so that `requests.request()` can read it. Also, it would be best to use the absolute path of the file, to avoid such errors.

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to download it directly from Qualtrics

Comment: Ah I see, in that case you shouldn't use the `files=` parameter, just submit the request and write the response (`r.content` in the example above) to file.

Comment: I see so this might be a different question: I post it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59074289/download-survey-results-from-qualtrics-into-pyrhon

As I am struggling to get it done