# Download survey results from Qualtrics into Python

Tags: python-3.x, qualtrics

I am trying to directly get the data responses from Qualtrics directly into a pandas dataframe python. Is there a way of doing so?

```
import shutil
import os
import requests
import zipfile
import json
import io

# Setting user Parameters
# apiToken = "myKey"
# surveyId = "mySurveyID"
# fileFormat = "csv"
# dataCenter = "az1" 

apiToken = "HfDjOn******"
surveyId = "SV_868******"
fileFormat = "csv"
dataCenter = 'uebs.eu'

# Setting static parameters
requestCheckProgress = 0
progressStatus = "in progress"
baseUrl = "https://{0}.qualtrics.com/API/v3/responseexports/".format(dataCenter)
headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-api-token": apiToken,
    }
```

Then for # Step 1: Creating Data Export

```
downloadRequestUrl = baseUrl
```

then when i try to access the url from my chrom it gives me the following

```
{"meta":{"httpStatus":"404 - Not Found","error":{"errorMessage":"The requested resource does not exist."}}}
```

Which I believe the main reason why after running this code

```
# Step 1: Creating Data Export
downloadRequestUrl = baseUrl
downloadRequestPayload = '{"format":"' + fileFormat + '","surveyId":"' + surveyId + '"}'
downloadRequestResponse = requests.request("POST", downloadRequestUrl, data=downloadRequestPayload, headers=headers)
progressId = downloadRequestResponse.json()["result"]["id"]
print(downloadRequestResponse.text)
```

It gives me this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-cd611e49879c> in <module>
      3 downloadRequestPayload = '{"format":"' + fileFormat + '","surveyId":"' + surveyId + '"}'
      4 downloadRequestResponse = requests.request("POST", downloadRequestUrl, data=downloadRequestPayload, headers=headers)
----> 5 progressId = downloadRequestResponse.json()["result"]["id"]
      6 print(downloadRequestResponse.text)

KeyError: 'result
```

I am somehow new to Qualtrics/python interface may someone share why I am having this difficulty is it because of the dataCenter?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see any significant errors in your code (I would use `requests.post()` and pass the data to the `json=` parameter, but I don't think that it would fix the HTTP 404 error). Maybe the error is caused by an invalid survey Id? Also, your current code uses the [Legacy Create Response Export](https://api.qualtrics.com/reference#create-response-export) API, have you tried with the new [Create Response Export](https://api.qualtrics.com/reference#create-response-export-new) API?

Comment: cul? I am not so familiar with this but when trying to sign in to Qualtrics to read my url 'https://uebs.eu.qualtrics.com/responses/#/surveys/SV_868****' which is different than the one proposed. i.e. there is no dataCenter or API\ and so on! which is weird.

Comment: That's the example code I found in the official API documentation; you don't have to use CURL, and you shouldn't use their ID, which is probably provided only for demonstration purposes. Your Python code should produce a request very similar to their CURL example code. The only important difference I see is the slash at the end of the URL, and it could cause a 404 response, so try without it.

Comment: @t.m.adam I tried without it but did not work still giving me 404 error. Is it because I do not have dataCenter similar to the one provided in the examples?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. As I said, your code is very similar to their example code, and I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work. I'm afraid I won't be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I know Stack typically frowns upon a response with a recommendation to use a different programming language but given R’s similarity to Python and the fact that this hasn’t been resolved after 3 years, I thought I’d share something I saw in a YouTube video. Essentially R’s qualRics package makes this super easy with 6 lines of code.

```
#Enter API info
qualtrics_api_credentials(api_key = "YOUR API KEY HERE", 
                          base_url = "yourdatacenterid.qualtrics.com/")

#This fetches a list of all of your surveys 
surveys <- all_surveys() 

#Set Time Zone
Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")

#Select survey to download
mysurvey <- fetch_survey(surveyID = "YOUR SURVEY ID HERE")

# Save responses to a CSV file
write.csv(mysurvey, file = "Demo_survey_responses.csv", row.names = FALSE)

#YouTube video reference: https://youtu.be/eX7fH_wR-ws
```

Answer (score 0):

Your base url is wrong, it should like this: `https://yul1.qualtrics.com/API/v3/surveys/{surveyId}/export-responses`

1. You did not put your id
2. You wrote responseexports instead of export-responses

See: https://api.qualtrics.com/5e86e383167d5-getting-survey-responses-via-the-new-export-ap-is